# commenting on whether $f'(x)$ is even or odd.

Tags: functions, partial-derivative, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics, even-and-odd-functions

The question is as follows:

Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function $\forall  x,y \in \Bbb R$ and $$f(x-y),f(x),f(y),f(x+y)$$ are in AP then comment whether $f'(x)$ is even or odd (given $f(0) \neq 0)$.

My approach :

Since the given sequence is an AP, hence we can say that

$$2f(x) = f(x-y)+f(y) \text{ and } 2f(y) = f(x)+f(x+y)$$
replacing $x$ and $y$ in $2f(x) = f(x-y)+f(y)$ and comparing with $2f(y) = f(x)+f(x+y)$ gives

$$f(x+y)=f(x-y)$$ putting  $x=0$ gives  $f(y)=f(-y)$ making $f'(x)$ an odd function.

But since,
$$2f(x) = f(x-y)+f(y)$$ now partially differentiating with respect to $y$ and putting $y=0$ we get $f'(x)=f'(0)$

Also $$2f(y) = f(x)+f(x+y)$$ now partially differentiating with respect to $y$ and putting $y=0$ we get $f'(x)=2f'(0)$ now this is a clear contradiction to previous equation.

So is $f'(x)$ odd or not? Kindly help me out.

Comment: What is the contradiction? Don't you get that $f'(0) = 2f'(0)$ and so $f'(0) = 0$? In turn, that would give you $f'(x) = 0$? (A function that is both even and odd.)

Comment: Please, write the definition of "is in AP".

Comment: @Crostul Arithmetic progression.

Comment: When you differentiate $f(x+y)$ w.r.t $y$ you get $f'(x+y)$ not $f'(y)$.

Comment: @saulspatz yes you are right, I did the same and rearranged terms so it looks like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $f(x-y),f(x),f(y),f(x+y)$ is an Arithmetic Progression implies that $$f(x-y)+f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$

Substituting $y=0$ gives us $$2f(x)=f(x)+f(0)\to f(x)=f(0)$$This tells us that the function is constant, i.e., $f'(x)=0$, so it is even and odd.

Your work is perfectly fine. Your last equation implies that $f'(x)=0$, but I think the proof I've presented is a bit simpler.

Comment: Great. _But_ the four numbers $0,3,5,8$ do not form an  arithmetic progression.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Wow that was an oversight. Fixed